# Inherited control cannot be found in form design mode

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a C# Windows Form project with Visual Studio 2019. I have inherited a new control, called NewGroupBox, from `System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`, the control is under name space `MyProject.NewCtrls` and was added through the standard procedure [How to: Inherit from Existing Windows Forms Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-inherit-from-existing-windows-forms-controls). I did not do any change on the code generated except changing `public partial class NewGroupBox: Control` to `public partial class NewGroupBox: GroupBox`

In the main frame, I have a GroupBox object called groupbox_Table.

```
groupBox_Table = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
```

The form designer could open normal. However, if I manually changed GroupBox with NewGroupBox

```
groupBox_Table = new MyProject.NewCtrls.NewGroupBox();
```

The form designer cannot be opened properly. The error message shows "Could not find type 'MyProject.NewCtrls.NewGroupBox' ...". Of course the type is defined in my project and there is no error when building the project.

How do I fix this problem so that form designer can open normally? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Disregarding other issues, I remember from the old days of windows forms, controls can be a bit fickle. try cleaning and rebuilding, closing the designer, restarting visual studio, maybe delete bin and obj directories in your solution(may help), hold you breath and recite the alphabet backwards while tapping one foot, stuff like that... and it may just work

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have tried cleaning solution and rebuilding it, deleting bin and obj folders etc. The problem still there. The funny thing is that the former design could be opened properly even GroupBox was changed to NewGroupBox. But I, by mistake, set C# editor as default editor in "Open with..." dialog box. Later I changed back to C# Form Editor, the form designer  could not be open.

Comment: what VS version?

Comment: Hi, The version is Visual studio 2019